# Hide Page title in SharePoint using js code

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am trying to hide the page title from my sharepoint site using javascript. I've found this article here but that solution does not seem to work for me. [LINK](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/407919-step-by-step-on-removing-page-title-in-sharepoint-2013)

I want to be able to find title by anchor tag not by ID. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to select any element in the document. This function accepts any CSS selector as an argument.

To select an anchor tag use `querySelector('a')`. You can also select ID's using `querySelector('#idname')` or classes using `querySelector('.className')`.

To hide the element:

```
querySelector([selector]).style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

or remove the element from the document flow using:

```
querySelector([selector]).style.display = 'none';
```

Replace [selector] with the selector of the element you wish to target.

Bear in mind that `querySelector()` only selects a single element. To select all elements that match the selector use [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Comment: Thank you for your response, Can you please provide a code snippet example? I have this code from the website i reference earlier.


`<script language="javascript">
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("HideBrandingsuite");
function HideBrandingsuite()
{
document.getElementById('pageTitle').style.visibility = 'hidden';
} 
</script>`